# Different Static Array Sizes at Compile Time

Tags: c++, embedded

Suppose I have a class that has an array in it. At compile time I know how big the arrays are going to be. How can I make instances of this class with different sized arrays?

```
class MyClass {
    private:
        const unsigned size;
        int data[size];
    /* More stuff here... */
}

MyClass c1(4);    /* Array size of 4  */
MyClass c2(16);   /* Array size of 16 */
```

I cannot use new/delete because dynamic memory is out. I also cannot use templates as I am primarily targeting embedded systems. Is this kind of thing even possible without templates?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what does "targeting embedded platforms" have to do with not being able to use templates?

Comment: @Borgleader, pretty much exactly nothing.

Comment: @Borgleader: There *is* a...thing called "Embedded C++" that doesn't include templates (or namespaces, or quite a few other parts of C++). It never achieved much popularity though, and AFAIK it's been pretty much a dead issue for years.

Comment: Even those vendors that do support Embedded C++ to tend to extend it with template support.  (Basically, RTTI, exceptions, and STL are usually left out.)

Comment: Why is statically-defined dynamic memory allocation "out"?  There's no practical difference between newing something off the heap (then never deleting it) and statically defining it somewhere else.  Generally, as long as you don't 'new' in response to some event or frequently new and delete something, there's nothing evil with non-statically allocated memory.

Comment: @Ross: You make a good point that I didn't consider.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using templates, as in the following example:

```
template <int size>
class MyClass {
    private:
        int data[size];
        /* More stuff here... */
};  

MyClass<4> c1 ;    /* Array size of 4  */
MyClass<16> c2;   /* Array size of 16 */
```

Comment: The `mSize` is worse than useless, as the template parameter is always available

Comment: True, I did that to be consistent with the original code, but in this case it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Does this generate separate code for Class functions like `template<typename T>` would if creating classes of different types?

Comment: Yes, the two classes are of different type. Is that desirable? If not, you can always make a wrapper over it (using inheritance and composition).